# How to use image in Customer Portal header HTML, without using Image ID?

Tags: customer-portal, css, html, images

Documentation says I can choose an HTML file for header image in Customer Portal. Searching on the internet is showing that people have uploaded the image on Documents, and referring to the ID of this Document image in their HTML file. This means that after deployment, I will have to manually change the ID in my HTML file. I want the solution to be sustainable, i.e., no maintenance should be needed after deployment. Is there a way to add an image banner without using ID?

Can you provide me the snippet of HTML code?

> Edit: In case I use Header Logo field in Customer Portal, the image
>   will get scaled down to 300px width, like the screenshot below. Hence
>   I can't use this approach if I have to add a Customer Portal image
>   banner covering full width of the page, just above the tabs. Also, in
>   case of using Logo field, the image will have to be less than 20 KiB.
>
> [image]

Comment: I am not sure why you want to add as html .Please see my answer .You can change the header logo as needed .

Comment: @MohithKumar, I can't use logo field, because image logos are getting scaled down to 300px width. Hence I can't use this approach if I have to add a Customer Portal image banner covering full width of the page, just above the tabs. Also, in case of using Logo field, the image will have to be less than 20 KiB.

Comment: .I see .Upvoting the question and deleted my answer .Also mention these points in question so that the question is crystal clear!Cheers!

Comment: @MohithKumar, thank you for your suggestion. I have mentioned these points in my question and added a screenshot of why I cannot use header logo field.

Comment: Excellent!This will give better understanding and also ensure you will get proper response and suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will smell *horrendous* but I'm guessing you want HTML in the portal header for good reason ;-)

Upload it as a Static Resource and use JavaScript `UserContext.siteUrlPrefix` to resolve the path:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(
    "<img " +
      "src='" + UserContext.siteUrlPrefix + "/resource/yourImagePng'" +
    "/>"
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, not working. I don't think that `UserContext` can work in non-VF HTML pages.

Comment: It'll only work in a Force.com Site or Customer Portal via your HTML header. If you inspect the DOM, what is the URL that ends up in your `img` tag?

Comment: Hey @BarneyRubble, that's JavaScript, not Visualforce - please try again carefully.

Comment: Thank you for stubbornly sticking around! It works perfectly. Since this functionality is undocumented and in case Salesforce changes the URL for accessing Static Resources later, do you see any issues in the future?

Comment: :-) maybe take a look at [Chatter Communities](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/features/communities.jsp) which offers better customization options

Answer (score 0):

In my case it also worked without the siteUrl prefix (and adherent javascript). 
So I just put:

```
<link href="/resource/PartnerPortalAssets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for my css file

which would translate to:

```
<img src="/resource/yourImagePng" />
```

for your image

Comment: nice - simpler is always better, just note it won't work on any Site with a `Name`...

Comment: good point! Also on Communities this might not work.